# 1С 7.7: как получить значение поля Основание в документе?

Tags: 1с

Использую 1С 7.7. В документе "Приходная накладная (кредит)" есть поле "Основание". Есть 2 случая использования этого поля. В одном случае оно пустое, а в другом заполненное. Как прогаммно проверить это поле на пустоту? И возможно ли это сделать в условии запроса? Т.е. выбрать данные если это поле пустое и наоборот если не пустое? В регистре это поле вроде как не сохраняется

Comment: А какой тип у реквизита "Основание"?

Answer (score 0):

```
ПустоеЗначение(Основание) = 1.
```

Также можно в запросе, только в запросе нужно сначала идентифицировать Основание, для примера:

```
ТекОснование = Документ.ПриходнаяНакладнаяКредит.Основание;
Условие(ПустоеЗначение(ТекОснование) = 1);
```